# Nutch parise and index Open Graph metatag

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using Nutch 1.10 and Solr 6.4, and have a problem to parse/index Open Graph metatags, like

```
<meta property="og:description" content="xyz.">.

following nutch-site.xml config works for metatag.description,metatag.keywords,metatag.twitter:description, but it's failed for metatag.og:description. 
Appreciate any helps.


    <property>
        <name>metatags.names</name>
        <value>*</value>
        <description></description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>metatags.property</name>
        <value>*</value>
        <description></description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>index.parse.md</name>
        <value>metatag.description,metatag.keywords,metatag.twitter:description,metatag.og:description</value>
        <description></description>
    </property>
```

Comment: I can fetch and index  metatag.description,metatag.keywords,metatag.twitter:description, metadata from a web page, but above configure seems ignore any og:description metadata, which is also in the same web page.  Not sure what i did wrong.  Thank you.